# How to use tailwind with contentContainerStyle in react native?

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css, nativewindow

I prefer using tailwind in my react-native app.So, i have configured nativewind. But now I do not know how to use tailwind classnames with contentContainerStyle.

is there way i can define new prop for contentContainerStyle like i did for className ?